# Not display image in actionBar

Tags: java, android, xml

Sorry for my english. I try display image in actionBar. I step by step perform tutorial, but when i finished tutorial i have not display image in action bar( I have not error and i have not display image in action bar. Please help me fix this problem

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.bonsitetest.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
     android:id="@+id/item1"
     android:showAsAction="always"
     android:title="@string/item1">
    </item>

    <item
     android:id="@+id/item2"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
     android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:title="@string/item2">
    </item>

    <item
     android:id="@+id/item3"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
     android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
     android:title="@string/item3">
    </item>

    <item
     android:id="@+id/item4"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
     android:showAsAction="never"
     android:title="@string/item4">
    </item>

</menu>
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">bonsiteTest</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string name="item1">Item1</string>
    <string name="item2">Item2</string>
    <string name="item3">Item3</string>
    <string name="item4">Item4</string>

</resources>
```

Main

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of items you don't see?

I've used your code and after changing first menu item's property `app:showAsAction="never"` to `android:showAsAction="never"` everything was working fine. I was able to see a *phone* icon and *information* icon.